# RxJS mouseenter between first and second clicks

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to capture hover events on a list of items between the first and second clicks of any of items in the list.

E.g.

- User clicks item in list
- Hover stream items emits event
- User performs second click in list and hover events stop

I have setup an observable stream as follows:

```
let items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
let itemClicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(items, "click");
let itemHover = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(items, "mouseenter");

let clicksWithFlag = itemClicks.scan((acc, val) => ({ val: val.target.innerHTML, firstClick: !acc.firstClick}), {});

//create stream of 1st clicks
let firstClicks = clicksWithFlag.filter(x => x.firstClick).pluck('val');
//create stream of second clicks
let secondClicks = clicksWithFlag.filter(x => !x.firstClick).pluck('val');

let hoverBetweenFirstAndSecondClick = firstClicks.flatMap(x => itemHover.takeUntil(secondClicks));
```

The problem I am running into is the `itemHover.takeUntil(secondClicks)` doesn't end the itemHover stream. I think it's related to firstClicks and secondClicks stemming from the same observable, but can't figure it out.

It works if I swap the takeUntil(secondClicks) for any other stream (e.g. a stop button).

See this JSBin for an example: https://jsbin.com/dotapis/edit?js,console,output

Hope somebody can help. I am trying to build a range selector using RxJS, but am starting to think that splitting the stream into first and second clicks may not be the best route.

### Update

Just tried this with BaconJS and I can get it working with pretty much the exact same code. https://jsbin.com/fobumu/edit?js,console,output

I'm convinced the problem lies in non-idiomatic use of streams, but not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you might be trying to force an imperative approach into a functional programming library, that's why it's becoming so complicated to make it work.
This might be simpler:

```
let items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
let button = document.getElementById("button1");

let itemClicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(items, 'click');
let itemHover = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(items, 'mouseenter');

let buttonClicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');

let clicksWithFlag = itemClicks.scan((acc, val) => (
  { val: val.target.innerHTML, firstClick: !acc.firstClick}
), {});

clicksWithFlag
  .combineLatest(itemHover, (click, hover) => ({click, hover}))
  .filter(arg => arg.click.firstClick)
  .map(arg => arg.hover.target.innerHTML)
  .subscribe(hover => console.warn('btn: hover: ' + hover));
```

As a general advise when working with Rx, try to find declarative solutions. If you start thinking how you transform a stream in order to get what you need instead of the steps to make that, things become easier.

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I tried to follow a similar pattern to the one I saw on the RXJs documentation. Still a bit puzzled as to why it works in BaconJS but not RXJs.